# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower()

Tags: function, centos

i have a vps server i installed nginx + php-fpm now i have a problem with mb_strtolower() function  this is my php info pleas goto this adress to see my php info

```
http://207.182.153.237/test.php
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: First step would be posting `test.php` here... Besides, please do not link to random external websites, rather, cut the exact error message and paste it here. Thanks.

Comment: error  : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower() in /usr/share/nginx/chatern.com/fm.php on line 2487

Answer (score 20):

You need to install the PHP multibyte extension ("mbstring") as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php).

Comment: Thanks Phil Rykoff.
this work for me, i am using php56. : 

sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring &&
sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 4):

Search in your `php.ini` for this line:

```
;zend.multibyte = Off
```

And change it to:

```
zend.multibyte = On
```

Comment: Have you restarted your php-fpm-instance?

Comment: What operating system are you running? If Linux, which distribution? Are you using a package manager or have you compile php by your own?

Comment: im using linux centos I've only installed nginx+php-fpm+mysql

Comment: I can give you my root password.You can log into the root to fix the problem?

Comment: Hooray for boobies, root passwords for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers from Phil Rykoff and omeinusch: this is my configure line to build php from source to support reportico 3.2 on php 5.4.43 / Centos 7.1.1503

```
/configure --with-apxs2=/opt2/canal/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql
--with-pdo-mysql --prefix=/opt2/canal/php --enable-mbstring --with-gd
```

--enable-mbstring is pertinent to this question.
(--with-gd required from image handling (also needed yum install libpng-devel to avoid missing png.h message))

Then needed to set the following in php.ini:

```
zend.multibyte = On
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cPanel hosting, you can go to PHP Selector and check the "mbstring" feature. It worked for me.